# Mysql UPDATE does not work with INNER JOIN on server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I have an query:

```
UPDATE production.review_comments as t2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT review_id as id FROM production.company_reviews 
    WHERE company_reviews.company_id = 1
) as t1 on t1.id = t2.id
SET t2.body = REPLACE(t2.body, 'qwerty', 'ytrewq')
WHERE t2.id != 0;
```

0 changes and 0 found

but query:

```
SELECT review_id as id FROM production.company_reviews 
    WHERE company_reviews.company_id = 1
```

has a result: 1, 2, 3 and review_comments has this ids on production.
On local this query works, but on production 0 founds or changes. Maybe there is some mysql settings on server?

I want to know what could be the reason

Comment: This is a very basic query, there are no server settings that would affect it. You must be wrong that those ids exist in `review_comments`.

Comment: Try using `REPAIR INDEX`, a corrupted index could prevent the join from working properly.